# Specific tree data structure in java

Tags: java, data-structures, arraylist, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to implement a specific tree data structure in Java; I don't know exactly what type of tree is this. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
             -----------------------------
            | Board                       |
            |
            | Node1  Node2  Node3  Node4  |
            |   _      _      _      _
            |  |_|    |_|    |_|    |_|   |
             ---+------+------+------+----
                |      |      |      |
               /       |      |       \
 --------------       ---    ---     -----------
| Board        |       -      -     | Board     |
|                                   |           
| Node1  Node2 |                    | Node1 ... |
|   _      _                        |   _       
|  |_|    |_|  |                    |  |_|  ... |
 ---+------+---                      ---+------+ 
   /       |                            |
   .       .                            .
   .       .                            .
   .       .                            .
```

So I created two classes: `Board` and `Node`.

- Each `Board` consists of an `ArrayList` of `Nodes`:

  ```
  public class Board {
      ArrayList<Node> mContent;

      Board() {
          mContent = new ArrayList<Node>();
      }

      Board(Board pBoard) {
          mContent = new ArrayList<Node>(pBoard.mContent);
      }

      void add(Node pNode) {
          mContent.add(pNode);
      }

      void add(String pString, Board pBoard) {
          Node tNode = new Node(pString, pBoard);
          mContent.add(tNode);
      }
  }
  ```
- Each `Node` consists of a `String` and a reference to another `Board`:

  ```
  public class Node {
      String mLabel;
      Board mBoard;

      Node(){
          mLabel = new String();
          mBoard = null;
      }

      Node(String pLabel, Board pBoard){
          mLabel = new String(pLabel);
          mBoard = new Board(Board);
      }

      void setBoard(Board pBoard){
          mBoard = pBoard;
      }
  }
  ```

My questions are:

- On the `add(Node pNode)` method, do I need to create a new `Node` and then add it to the `ArrayList`?
- On the `setBoard(...)` method, do I need to create a new `Board` and then pass it to `mBoard`, or just doing `mBoard = pBoard` is correct?
- How do I indicate a leaf `Node`? I tried to initialize it with `null`, but I got a `NullPointerException`

Thank you!

Comment: since your parent-child relationships are on nodes-boards, you should implement a pointer from a node to board objects. the structure is dangling without that.

Comment: @Roam, I'm not sure if my implementation is correct, but wouldn't that `Board mBoard` from the `Node` class work as a pointer to a `Board` object?

Comment: The purpose of `Board` here is a little bit confusing.  Normally the nodes in a tree are represented by a class called `Node` which contains a reference to the data that needs to be held and references to its children and parent.  I.e. Consider combining `Board` into `Node`.

Comment: @increment1 - how should I keep a reference to a parent `Board`? By passing the parent as a parameter of the constructor?

Comment: Yep, that is usually how it is done.  If nodes can be moved then you need a setter / getter for it as well.

Comment: @horta yes, i would. giving you the link from parent-to-child and is there.

Comment: @increment1 - Great, I'll implement these now, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question:

- The `Node` passed as `pNode` should be used; you don't need to create a new one.
- The `Board` passed as `pBoard` should be used; you don't need to create a new one.
- A leaf node has a null `mBoard`. Alternatively, it could have an `mBoard` that has an empty `mContent` array. The choice depends on information you have not posted about how you want your trees to bottom out.

You might consider collapsing your structure. It's not clear why you don't just have a single `Node` class (with an `ArrayList<Node> mContent` field in place of the mBoard field).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt help! Actually, to build the tree, these `Nodes` will come from an `ArrayList source` from another class. If I change its content on the Tree (e.g.: a `String mLabel` of a `Node`), will it affect the original Node too? (the one from the `ArrayList source`)

Comment: And collapsing the structure really seems to be much cleaner, even though the `Board`class has other attributes on my original code (I tried to make it simpler before posting here).